# Define a contract using query string parameter in json path assertion

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to use SCC to write some contracts before I rebuild the producer side (there are no existing tests!). The examples around lists and deeper data structures in the documents are a bit thin, so I want to understand if this is feasible, or perhaps I have to drop down to calling a command to make the right assertions.
I'm using the latest version v2.11

So -

**Given**:
An API that will return a list of objects in its payload. The length of the list will depending on the identity of the client, i.e. client A will get 3 items, client B will get 4 items. The identity of the client isn't of interest here.

**When**:
A client makes a GET request, passing a querystring parameter for item selection *within* the list of items

**Then**:
I want to write a contract that takes input from request and proves that the response contains a list of objects, and the item that matches the selector has a boolean field selected:true, while the rest of the items have selected:false. There's an edge where the selector is wrong and no item is selected.

E.g. For the request  `GET /someapi?id=bbb`

Response

```
{ foo: xxxy, bar: 123, baz: [
  { id: 'aaa', selected: false, .... },
  { id: 'bbb', selected: true, .... },
  { id: 'ccc', selected: false, .... }
] }
```

Of course the selected item can be anywhere in the list. So I had in mind an assertion like this pseudo code -

```
jsonPath('$.baz[?(@.id ==  fromRequest().query("id"))].selected', byEquality( true ) )
```

But I can't do that fromRequest() stuff in the JSONPath statement. Right now I guess I could simply have the whole response body as the spec, but that seems unwieldy. If it must be, that's fine I guess.

Any ideas or help appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can do  `fromRequest()` can work on jsonpaths. I guess you'll have to provide fixed values instead of the dynamic ones.

Comment: Right, thanks Marcin, you're reply is probably definitive here! I've set to use a fixed value but that gives me compilation error on generated Test class with error: illegal start of expression
assertThat(parsedJson.read("$.accounts[?(@.accountId == \"428540\")].selected", JSONArray.class)).isEqualTo([true]);

Comment: that's correct cause we don't support nested calls over JsonArrays. You jsonpath expression `$.accounts[?(@.accountId == \"428540\")]` returns a list of responses from which you're trying to retrieve a value `true`. You'd have to do sth like this `$.baz[0].selected`. Also `byEquality()` doesn't accept a parameter. It assumes that it should be equal with what you've provided in the response. My suggestion is to use `byCommand(...)` and pass there the value of `$.baz[?(@.id ==  fromRequest().query("id"))]` and use Java to assert the value of the `selected` field.